# AWS "errorMessage": "'s3_cleansed_layer'", "errorType": "KeyError" please check

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

```
import awswrangler as wr
import pandas as pd
import urllib.parse
import os

# Temporary hard-coded AWS Settings; i.e. to be set as OS variable in Lambda
os_input_s3_cleansed_layer = os.environ['s3_cleansed_layer']
os_input_glue_catalog_db_name = os.environ['glue_catalog_db_name']
os_input_glue_catalog_table_name = os.environ['glue_catalog_table_name']
os_input_write_data_operation = os.environ['write_data_operation']


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    try:

        # Creating DF from content
        df_raw = wr.s3.read_json('s3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, key))

        # Extract required columns:
        df_step_1 = pd.json_normalize(df_raw['items'])

        # Write to S3
        wr_response = wr.s3.to_parquet(
        df=df_step_1,
            path=os_input_s3_cleansed_layer,
            dataset=True,
            database=os_input_glue_catalog_db_name,
            table=os_input_glue_catalog_table_name,
            mode=os_input_write_data_operation
    )

    return wr_response
    except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same        region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
    raise e
```

**  AWS getting above error, I have given environment details also **
[environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5qkp.png)

everything I followed using Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZKJFKu49Dk

Comment: Key error means the bucket object you are trying to access is not present, can you confirm the object exists?

Comment: yes, it is present but if I write in environment variable it did not work and if I write it in .py file it worked, can you please help with this? @furydrive

Comment: guess try enclose the env variable in `" "` when you pass it in so if your key is `mykey` then do it like `"mykey"`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I realised, there was a spelling mistake in the environment variable 'key' name and the one used in the code. (s3_cleansed_data)

If this is not the issue for you, then try creating a new folder inside the s3 bucket you have created to store the cleaned data. (s3://dataengg-on-youtube-cleansed-useast-1-x/u)

I see in the above path that the folder name is 'u'.
Try with the correct folder name or create a new folder in the s3 bucket and specify that respective name in the above path. (value for the s3 key, in environment variables) .

Hope this helps!